# lowercase or uppercase and with or without definite article

Tags: definite-article, capitalization

This is the sentence I have:

> "Then we need not worry about anything on earth!"

Should I use Earth or is it okay to leave it as such?
I understand Earth as an element has to be capitalized. I also see a number of occurrences where it is used in lowercase without a "the" I am so confused about this. My gut feeling says, I should write it as,

> Then we need not worry about anything on this earth"

There is one more sentence about which I am almost sure it has to be this way:

> > Is it not by God's grace we are born on Earth?

Am I correct about this? reason: It is earth as in a planet, we are referring to.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You have guessed correctly that in different contexts a capital 'E' or lower case 'e' is needed.

This is because 'Earth' can be both a proper noun (ie the name) for the planet we live on, as well as a common noun used to describe the planet, as well as the soil and dirt it is made from.

A rough rule can be said to be 'capitalize when "the" is missing'.

> Mars is red, but Earth is blue and green.

> The astronaut crashed into the earth.

Even then, is a somewhat vaguely implemented rule, and both omitting or adding capitals may pass unnoticed by English speakers, even if technically 'wrong', while certain idiomatic phrases like 'heaven and earth' also break the 'rules'.

In your two examples you have made the correct choices to use lower case and upper case.

More:

- [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/earth/).
- [Grammarist.com](https://grammarist.com/style/earth/).